# Duplicate .java file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I'm looking for something like the refactoring function in Eclipse but for copying files, i.e. I want to keep the existing file, but add another one (typically an enum or similar).

Currently I do this by manually copying the file in the file system, then refreshing the folder in Project Explorer, then opening the file through Project Explorer, then search 'n replace, then I can start working. It can be a bit tedious as I often do this for 10+ files when I add a new major feature.

Comment: Why don't you just use the copy&paste function in eclipse?

Comment: Maybe [SVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) is what you looking for? U can use it to restore previous version of file. So you just save whole project and you have all files with all versions available

Comment: Just 10 files?  Not even worth the effort looking for an alternative ... IMO.  Better to spend the time looking for a better design that doesn't involve lots of copied code.

Comment: @Stephen C: I would design better if I could, but I think that would push us over the line between "copy pase" and "too complex code". We have a lot of functionality and GUI's that do similar, but not the same, things.

Comment: Maybe the GUI's need to be refactored (?)

Comment: Maybe in some way that I'm unable to see, but I constantly refactor.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In an Explorer view, select a file, right click and choose <kbd>Copy</kbd>. Now select the folder it's in, right click and choose <kbd>Paste</kbd>. You'll get a dialog asking for a new name, and you're done. Note that if you do this to a Java class, the new name will be used to rename the class in the file as well.

Comment: This is true, but it uses the clipboard. If the new file name was already on the clipboard, then the user must then switch somewhere (other than eclipse, since the copy dialog is modal) to copy it again, or type it in manually. If there was a true "duplicate" (like in MacOS Finder cmd-D) then the clipboard would not be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy and paste files within the package explorer of Eclipse.

Answer (score -2):

The question you should be asking your is: "Should I be copying files and making small changes to add a major feature?"

Don't Repeat Yourself is a bedrock principle of computer science, not to be abandoned lightly.

When you find yourself copying and tweaking blocks, methods, or classes you should immediately see if it's possible to refactor to eliminate the duplication.

I think that's more important than knowing the particular technique in Eclipse.

Comment: in principle you are correct, and I don't take DRY lightly, but in this case I find that path even harder than the copy-paste madness (otherwise I wouldn't do it).

Comment: Yeah, boy, this is a +1/-1 answer for my tastes. I completely agree with what you're saying, but I still find myself doing this cut/paste dance all the time, often as a way of creating classes in an inheritance hierarchy. Cut/paste/edit doesn't necessarily imply duplication, just similarity.

Comment: "Even harder" seems like an excuse to me.  I'd push myself more.

Comment: @duffymo: again I would if it was only me, but the n00bs on the project are already hurting from the complexity now. I haven't seen it first-hand, but a friend of mine told me some research indicates that it's more productive to mentor the n00bs than to keep adding complexity in code. That makes sense to me.

Comment: Can't imagine why this was voted down three years after the fact.

Comment: Just look at Ernest's comment. There are plenty of perfectly legit reasons to do that.

Comment: A useless comment that is four years old?  Please.  DRY is fundamental. No arguing with that.

Comment: So you didn't understand it. I won't argue. We are simply in a real world were real problems happen.

Comment: I did understand it. Maybe your problem is that you're stuck with Eclipse and noob developers. You have my sympathy on both counts. Ernest's comment says he agrees with me. Is your reading comprehension the problem?

Comment: Ok, stop it already. Begin by reading his comment to the end.

Comment: I did read it FOUR YEARS AGO. get over yourself.  By all means keep being "practical" & cut and paste duplicate code all you like. No one is stopping you from making a mess.